# How to write to RFID tag using RFIDLibrary by Zebra?

Tags: android

I'm using RFD2000(sled) by zebra and RFIDAPILibrary(sdk). I cannot write in an EPC tag is there any problem with my code?

```
    public void wri(String sourceEPC, String targetData) {
    Log.d(TAG, "WriteTag " + targetData);
    try {
        TagData tagData = null;
        String tagId = sourceEPC;
        TagAccess tagAccess = new TagAccess();
        TagAccess.WriteAccessParams writeAccessParams = tagAccess.new WriteAccessParams();
        String writeData = targetData; 
        writeAccessParams.setOffset(0); 
        writeAccessParams.setWriteData(writeData);
        writeAccessParams.setMemoryBank(MEMORY_BANK.MEMORY_BANK_EPC);
        writeAccessParams.setWriteRetries(3);
        writeAccessParams.setWriteDataLength(writeData.length() / 4);
        reader.Actions.TagAccess.writeWait(tagId, writeAccessParams, null, tagData);
        Log.e("Tag data ", tagData.getTagID());
    } catch (InvalidUsageException | OperationFailureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I am getting this error:

I am getting this type of error:

```
W/System.err: com.zebra.rfid.api3.OperationFailureException
W/System.err:     at com.zebra.rfid.api3.bk.a(SourceFile:16)
        at com.zebra.rfid.api3.TagAccess.writeWait(SourceFile:242)
W/System.err:     at com.zebra.rfid.api3.TagAccess.writeWait(SourceFile:257)
```

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So after looking though several of Zebra's examples, tech docs and sdk docs I finally found a solution online that works for me using a Zebra 8500 and Zebra RFID for Android (I'm using Zebra SDK 2.0.1.19).

Turns out that before you do any read or write operations you need to make sure Inventory is stopped. You also need to turn off DPO (DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION).

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/Write-to-RFID-Tag-Using-Zebra-RFID-Application-for-iOS-Device.html

With that in mind, your example should work by adding the extra lines below

```
public void wri(String sourceEPC, String targetData) {
    Log.d(TAG, "WriteTag " + targetData);
    try {

        // make sure Inventory is stopped
        reader.Actions.Inventory.stop();

        // make sure DPO is disabled
        reader.Config.setDPOState(DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION.DISABLE);


        TagData tagData = null;
        String tagId = sourceEPC;
        TagAccess tagAccess = new TagAccess();
        TagAccess.WriteAccessParams writeAccessParams = tagAccess.new WriteAccessParams();
        String writeData = targetData; 
        writeAccessParams.setOffset(0); 
        writeAccessParams.setWriteData(writeData);
        writeAccessParams.setMemoryBank(MEMORY_BANK.MEMORY_BANK_EPC);
        writeAccessParams.setWriteRetries(3);
        writeAccessParams.setWriteDataLength(writeData.length() / 4);
        reader.Actions.TagAccess.writeWait(tagId, writeAccessParams, null, tagData);
        Log.e("Tag data ", tagData.getTagID());

        //enable again 
        reader.Config.setDPOState(DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION.ENABLE);
        reader.Actions.Inventory.perform();

    } catch (InvalidUsageException | OperationFailureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```