# Zebra RFID API Read Access Operation Code return null

Tags: java, android, rfid

I'm trying to develop a small Application for a Zebra handheld rfid reader and can't find a way to access the MemoryBank of the tag. My reader configuration is as follows:

```
 private void ConfigureReader() {
    if (reader.isConnected()) {
        TriggerInfo triggerInfo = new TriggerInfo();
        triggerInfo.StartTrigger.setTriggerType(START_TRIGGER_TYPE.START_TRIGGER_TYPE_IMMEDIATE);
        triggerInfo.StopTrigger.setTriggerType(STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE.STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE_IMMEDIATE);
        try {
            // receive events from reader
            if (eventHandler == null){
                eventHandler = new EventHandler();
            }
            reader.Events.addEventsListener(eventHandler);
            // HH event
            reader.Events.setHandheldEvent(true);
            // tag event with tag data
            reader.Events.setTagReadEvent(true);
            reader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(true);
            // set trigger mode as rfid so scanner beam will not come
            reader.Config.setTriggerMode(ENUM_TRIGGER_MODE.RFID_MODE, true);
            // set start and stop triggers
            reader.Config.setStartTrigger(triggerInfo.StartTrigger);
            reader.Config.setStopTrigger(triggerInfo.StopTrigger);
        } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the eventReadNotify looks like this:

```
public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e) {
        // Recommended to use new method getReadTagsEx for better performance in case of large tag population
        TagData[] myTags = reader.Actions.getReadTags(100);
        if (myTags != null) {
            for (int index = 0; index < myTags.length; index++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());
                ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE aoc = myTags[index].getOpCode();
                ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS aos = myTags[index].getOpStatus();
                if (aoc == ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.ACCESS_OPERATION_READ && aos == ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS.ACCESS_SUCCESS) {
                    if (myTags[index].getMemoryBankData().length() > 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, " Mem Bank Data " + myTags[index].getMemoryBankData());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm scanning a tag I get the correct TagID but both `myTags[index].getOpCode()` and `myTags[index].getOpStatus()` return null values.

I appreciate every suggestion that might lead to a successful scan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for my problem. To perform any Read or Write task with Zebra Handheld Scanners the following two conditions must be satisfied. Look here for reference: [How to write to RFID tag using RFIDLibrary by Zebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548744/how-to-write-to-rfid-tag-using-rfidlibrary-by-zebra)

```
// make sure Inventory is stopped
reader.Actions.Inventory.stop();

// make sure DPO is disabled
reader.Config.setDPOState(DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION.DISABLE);
```

You have to stop the inventory and make sure to disable dpo in order to get data other than the TagID from a Tag. Unfortunately this isn't mentioned in the docu for Reading RFID Tags.